# Connect to Hive using Squirrel SQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, squirrel-sql

I started Hadoop, Hive metastore and Hwi using the following commands,

```
 sh start-all.sh
 bin/hive --service metastore
 bin/hive –service HWI
```

I then configured drivers with Squirrel SQL. The example URLs I have tried in my Squirrel SQL connection are

```
jdbc:hive://localhost:9999/default
jdbc:hive2://localhost:9999/default
jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

I then try to add an alias for each of these, but I get a connection refused from the 9999 URLs and an invalid URL from the 10000 URLs. I am following https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface#HiveJDBCInterface-IntegrationwithSQuirrelSQLClient reference guide from Apache Hive

Comment: You've started the metastore, but not HiveServer2... And did you add the JDBC Driver to SquirrelSQL? Otherwise, it shouldn't be invalid

Comment: @cricket_007  Yes, I added the `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` driver to SquirrelSQL as mentioned https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface#HiveJDBCInterface-IntegrationwithSQuirrelSQLClient post. I follow all 7 steps correctly but when I hit `Connect` in the 7th step, I get errors.

Comment: Are you able to use beeline with those jdbc addresses?